# Can't use VirtualBox shared folder as Apache document root

Tags: linux, virtualbox, apache-http-server, centos

Having jumped through several hundred hoops I've finally managed to get Centos 5.8 to mount a VirtualBox shared folder (which is *not* read-only), which now appears at:

```
/media/sf_sites
```

This is a folder on my host machine (Mac OS X 10.8.2) containing sites.

The directory and its subfolders are all owned by user `root` and group `vboxsf`

I have added the user `apache` to the group `vboxsf`

However **httpd** doesn't let me use my shared folder as Document root. My vhost is set up as:

```
DocumentRoot /media/sf_sites/mysite/public
```

On Apache restart I get this:

```
Starting httpd: Warning: DocumentRoot [/media/sf_sites/mysite/public] does not exist
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

And, unsurprisingly, when viewing the site in my browser I get a 403 error. ("You don't have permission to access / on this server.")

Any ideas whether it's possible to make this work?

I want to develop on my Mac but use Linux in VirtualBox as my development server. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never solved the 'unexpected end of file' issues, but then [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) came along and that does all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This because the SELinux security context of the shared folder does not allow Apache to use it. Since the security context of VBox shared folders cannot be changed, you can modify the SELinux security policy to allow Apache to work with the context. It is similar to opening a port in your firewall to expose a certain port to an application. It is NOT a good idea to turn off SELinux as others have suggested as this leaves your server more vulnerable.

First, make sure your apache user is part of the group which owns the shared folder, if it is not, you can add it with a command that would look like this (the user/group names can be different on your system):

```
usermod -aG vboxsf apache
```

Then, you can use [audit2allow](https://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow) to generate a new security policy to work around your issues. [Here is a good tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html).

If you are lazy and only want to allow Apache read access to your VBox shared folders, you can probably adapt the following `my_httpd_t.te` policy file and use the included commands to apply it on your system.

```
module my_httpd_t 1.0;

require {
        type httpd_t;
        type vmblock_t;
        class dir read;
        class file { read getattr open };
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t vmblock_t:dir read;
allow httpd_t vmblock_t:file { getattr open read };

# Generated by audit2allow

# To apply this policy:
## checkmodule -M -m -o my_httpd_t.mod my_httpd_t.te
## semodule_package -o my_httpd_t.pp -m my_httpd_t.mod
## semodule -i my_httpd_t.pp
## systemctl restart httpd
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a mount point in your Linux, install **sshfs** if you don't have it yet.

Do the following in CentOS

```
sudo su - apache
sshfs root@< your OS X IP >:< web folder path > < mount point >
```

For example:

- OS X IP: 192.168.0.10
- OS X web folder path: /Users/me/webOSX
- CentOS mount point: /var/www/webLinux

The sshfs command will be: **sshfs root@192.168.0.10:/Users/me/webOSX /var/www/webLinux**

Comment: This mounts successfully, but same problem:
`DocumentRoot [/var/www/sites/mysite/public] does not exist`

Comment: Update: got it to work with `user_allow_other` set in `/etc/fuse.conf` and `sshfs -o allow_other me@192.168.1.103:/Users/me/Sites /var/www/sites`.

But Apache throwing "unexpected end of file" errors into error_log.

Comment: @Abe, did you `sudo su - apache` before doing the sshfs mount?

Comment: Yes I did. It seemed to be basically working, but PHP is having problems with file lengths (unexpected end of file errors). Coming to the conclusion that back-end code is better off local on the server!

Answer (score -1):

You need to disable SELinux if you need to set a shared folder as the `DocumentRoot` of your Apache server.

Go to `/etc/selinux/config` and then update it to read:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#       targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#       mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Then reboot your virtual machine. This works with vagrant too.